# how do i block jquery.address from changing the url in certain situations

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-address

i use jquery.address, a plugin to do browser history state when having an ajax heavy website.
though, in a certain situation where a link would trigger the $.address.change() functions, this should be blocked.

for example, when having a navigation, where 1 element is the current page,
i would prefer it not to reload the current page, but to block the change event from happening.

in the $.address.change() function i can of course check if this is the current page, and just return, but i still see the address in the addressbar of the browser change.

this is even more wrong than reloading the page, as now it shows the current page with a wrong url to the user.

so if anybody has an idea how to block jquery.address from changing the url, for example when there link has the class 'current' on it?

best regards
Sander Houttekier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a click handler for the links along with a state tracking variable `m_page` or `m_currentFoo` etc, and then put an if statement checking if the link corresponds to the current state before changing the adress.

Here's the first code sample from their API page:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    // do something depending on the event.value property, e.g.
    // $('#content').load(event.value + '.xml');
});
$('a').click(function() {
    $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

And here's some modifications:

```
//This is called when the address is changed due to navigation.
$.address.change(function(event) {
    // do something depending on the event.value property, e.g.
    // $('#content').load(event.value + '.xml');
});

//This is your click handler
$('a').click(function() {
    //Do any logic for choosing what happens with the address here.
    if(moon = newMoon) {
        $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

Comment: but i have no power over the changing of the address... jquery.address plugin does that.  i can block it from doing anything there, but it does change the url in the address bar already.

a click event would be rather hard, i can but don't know what performance hit this will be, if i have to loop over all anchors in my page, to check whether they are the current state and bind a click on it to prevent it from going further.

Comment: @Sander See the updated answer. Does that explain it better? :)

Comment: aha ok yes i do now, the problem is that i invoke the address on lots of elements together, and not manually on every click...
lots of content is loaded with ajax, and i often update all elements
that were newly loaded like this $('a.ajax', container).address();
(with a bit more pparameters but this is just to give the Idea)
i might need to change it over to indivitual setup then i believe...

Comment: I think you need to split them up. I have different handlers for different types of links, and I couldn't have done it any other way. For some types of links I use url autoUpdate, for others I build the url in several steps.

Comment: thanks for all the input, i will make sure to take more time for this stuff in future projects :) because as soon as it gets complicated you need to start doing it like you say, custom handlers per linktype.
i had not foreseen that, thanks for the input!